# Solidity Keccak256 raw data vs abi encoded data

Tags: solidity, hash

I am new to solidity. I am trying to store some hash of the data to the blockchain. I saw some online tutorial used `keccak256(abi.encodePacked( <data input> ))` to calculate the hash. I am wondering why do we use `abi.encodePacked( <data input> )` to encode the raw data. What is the problem with `keccak256(raw data)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just comes down to what type is `<data input>`.

`keccak256` expects a byte array and nothing else. So if your data is already of type `bytes` there is no difference :

```
function equality() public pure returns (bool) {
 bytes memory test = "0x01020304";

 // True
 return keccak256(test) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(test));
}
```

If `<data input>` is of any other type, then `abi.encodePacked` or `abi.encode` are ways of converting a variable number of arguments, whith possibly different types, to `bytes` to allow for the use of keccak256.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: That makes a lot sense! Thanks.